# How to evaluates complex many to many relationships in core data using predicate?

Tags: ios, core-data, many-to-many, nspredicate

My app have 3 entity : `Folder`, `Feed`, `Item`. Folder and Feed both have many to many relationship as respect to each other : "`feeds`" and "`folders`", and Feed have a to many relationship "`items`" to Item, Item have a to one relationship "`feed`" to Feed. Now i have a Folder managed object contains several Feed managed objects, and i want to retrieve `all items in feeds of this particular folder`, how to achieve this using predicate? Appreciated to all helps.

Object Graph : Folder <<-->> Feed, Feed >--<< Item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can execute a fetch request on the "Item" entity with the predicate

```
[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY feed.folders == %@", theFolder]
```

Note that you would obtain the result also without a fetch request:

```
NSSet *items = [theFolder valueForKeyPath:@"feeds.item"];
```